# Symfony2 ChoiceList: Get the choise from the child element

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

Symfony2 ChoiceList: Get the choise from the child element

I am building form where I want to offer customer some additional products.

The first thing that came to my mind was to use the Choice Field Type especially when I can get the selected entity directly as output value.

```
$productNames = array();
    foreach ($this->products as $product){
        $productNames[] = $product->getName();
    }

    $builder->add('products', 'choice', array(
            'choice_list' => new ChoiceList(
                 $this->products,
                 $productNames
    ),
    'required' => false,
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => true
));
```

However I need to render more then the label so I need an access to the rendered entity in the view.

```
{% for child in form.products %}         
    <label for="{{ child.vars.id }}">
        {{ form_widget(child) }}{{ products[loop.index0].getDescription()}}
    </label>
{% endfor %}
```

So I am asking if is there any better way to get the entity (the choice) from the child element in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing this is to [create your own form type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) (that extends from the choice type) and that will render the extra information that you require.

So create your form type:

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        // set the options as you do above
        $resolver->setDefaults([ 'expanded' => true, ]);

        // this exposes a "products" option when adding this formtype
        $resolver->setRequired(['products']);
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        foreach ($options['products'] as $product) {
            // build your form as you do in your example above
        }
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        // this makes the "products" array available in your view
        $view->vars['products'] = $options['products'];
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_form_type';
    }
}
```

Then in your own form you would add this field type like:

```
$builder->add('my_form_type', [ 'products' => $products ]);
```

Then you create a view for your field:

```
{% block my_form_type_widget %}
    {% for child in form %}
        {{ form_widget(child) }} {{ products[loop.index0].description }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I've glossed over some of the other minutiae (adding the form type to your service descriptions, setting up your view as a Twig resource) as that's all covered in the [cookbook entry](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html). The above setup does required that the form options are in the same order as the `$products` array - otherwise the `loop.index0` won't match up. The only way around this would be to do something like the `Entity` field type which is quite complicated but is a good place to start if you want further development.

Comment: This is almost exactly  what I have. Synchronization with products is easy because the field used to create elements is the one used in the twig. But I am looking for a way around this completely.

Comment: Short version: no. Not without going ALL the way back with your form type (i.e. not extending on `choice` and doing your own base type) and cooking all of the different components yourself.

Comment: Sorry for long absence. Is there a way to add the product link to the ChoiceFieldType child?

Answer (score 0):

How about the entity Field Type with a [custom query](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities), more or less like this:

```
$builder->add('products', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'YourBundle:Product',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->orderBy('p.name', 'ASC');
    },
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => true
    'choice_label' => 'labelForSelectbox'
));
```

The query gets all products so you would probably have to limit the result with `where()` somehow.

For this to work you would have to add this getter in your `Product` entity:

```
public function getLabelForSelectbox()
{
    return $this->getName() . $this->getDescription();
}
```

Twig implementation concludes in:

```
{{ form_row(form.products) }}
```